# how to get uploaded file as blobs in servlet using google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I can use the below code to upload a file as blobs,

```
<form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="myFile">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

but in my case am using the [Apache Common File Uploader](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) to upload a file. So my form action will be as below,

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

now in my servlet am getting the file as InputStream. if i want to convert the file as blob in the same servlet file  how can i convert it. Kindly suggest me an idea.

**UPDATED**

I tried with the [Writing files to blob store](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Writing_files_to_the_Blobstore)  my code is as follows,

```
FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
AppEngineFile file = fileService.createNewBlobFile(mime,fileName);
boolean lock = true;
FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, lock);
byte[] b1 = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
int readBytes1 = is.read(b1, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
while (readBytes1 != -1) {
writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(b1, 0, BUFFER_SIZE));}
```

Now i can upload the file in app engine, it stores the blob values but i cant view the blob values. When i use `<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") %>` this line my app engine shows me "View Blob" option but now its not there.Also when i use the blob list to view the file its not showing and says "0" bytes. I think it just stores the blob key but not the file. Kindly suggest me an idea to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Use [provided blobstore upload functionality](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Uploading_a_blob): your client calls server which replies with one-time upload url (created via `blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload")`). Then you can use this url one-time-only with your Apache Common File Uploader.
2. Handle uploads in your code: [create a multipart handler](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/java#fileforms) and then [save data to blobstore programmatically via Files API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Writing_files_to_the_Blobstore).

Note that option 2. falls under standard GAE 32Mb request/response size limit. Option 1. has a 2Gb file upload limit.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```java
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        upload.setSizeMax(maxPostSize);

        for (FileItemIterator it = upload.getItemIterator(request); it.hasNext();) {
            FileItemStream item = it.next();
            final byte[] fileData = IOUtils.toByteArray(item.openStream());

            // store data

        }
```

Now store the `fileData` in the datastore. Make sure, you check if the `item` is a form field using `item.isFormField()`.

Or check out the [Streaming API](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/streaming.html).

Storing the file in the Blobstore is done [like this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Java_Uploading_a_blob), assuming you have the form field `<input type="file" name="myFile">`:

```java
Map<String, BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(request);
BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get("myFile");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you say from where to import this IOUtils

Comment: i tried with this sample link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837536/why-i-cant-upload-file-to-google-cloud-storage-that-larger-than-100kbyte-throug?rq=1  In the upload servlet i did as it shown and i can upload the data to cloud storage. what i need is how to convert the file as blobstore value

Comment: It's this `IOUtils`: https://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html

Comment: i had tried it already it shows me an error like this `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must be called from a blob upload callback request.`

Comment: FYI am not uploading a blob. Am uploading a normal file through apache file uploader. After i get the file in servlet i donno how to convert it into blob files

Comment: Did you try this: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore

Comment: `DiskFileItemFactory` will try to save (bigger) files into the filesystem, which will fail on GAE as filesystem is read-only.

Comment: ya i tried it but i don't know how to get the file. There i got stuck

Comment: @PeterKnego that's true, but the code above worked for me. Maybe it is more save to use the Streaming API.

Comment: You can probably configure it with higher limit: http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/disk/DiskFileItemFactory.html